# how to understand protocol buffers Varint rule?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I defined a proto message:

```
message Header{
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 tabletype =2;
  required int32 version = 3;
  required int32 precision = 4;
  required int32 numfields = 5;
}
```

and get a java file with protoc ;

then i transfer value to every fields;

```
    headerBuilder.setName("PLB");
    headerBuilder.setTabletype(84);
    headerBuilder.setPrecision(21);
    headerBuilder.setNumfields(4);
    headerBuilder.setVersion(0);
```

depends on the Varint rule:
The toByteArray should be :0x50(P) 0x4C(L) 0x42(B) 0x54(84) 0x00(0) 0x15(21) 0x04(4)

but in fact :

```
    for (byte b : header.toByteArray()) {
        System.out.print(b);
    }
```

10 38 07 66 61 68 42 40 32 21 40 4

Who can tell me why ?

Comment: If you want to understand a protobuf raw stream: try https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode - it'll pull it to pieces and show you what each part means

Comment: @MarcGravell Can not show correct part ,it notice some error:(

Comment: k, taking a look; but: what library are you using here? is that the Google Java tools? also, are those numbers *hex*, or *decimal*? (it matters)

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you should *expect* here are, in hex:

```
0A-03-50-4C-42-10-54-18-00-20-15-28-04
```

or in decimal:

```
10 3 80 76 66 16 84 24 0 32 21 40 4
```

So: I think you have simply mis-transcripted the data; compare and contrast against the numbers in the question:

```
10 38 07 66 61 68 42 40 32 21 40 4
```

Now take out the whitespace:

```
10380766616842403221404 -- mine
10380766616842403221404 -- yours
```

So you have the same *decimal digits*, but just: whitespace errors - that's important, because obviously `1 23` is very different to `12 3`.

---

In terms of *why* the data is `0A-03-50-4C-42-10-54-18-00-20-15-28-04`, you can plug the data [into here](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode?hex=0A-03-50-4C-42-10-54-18-00-20-15-28-04) to get a breakdown, but I'll copy it here:

---

0A = field 1, type String

03 = length 3

payload = 50-4C-42

UTF8: PLB

---

10 = field 2, type Variant

54 = 84 (raw) or 42 (zigzag)

---

18 = field 3, type Variant

00 = 0 (raw) or 0 (zigzag)

---

20 = field 4, type Variant

15 = 21 (raw) or -11 (zigzag)

---

28 = field 5, type Variant

04 = 4 (raw) or 2 (zigzag)

---

(note: for historic reasons, my tool has a typo where Variant===Varint)